# Настройка сети на виртуальной машине

Tags: ubuntu, сеть, virtualbox

На VirtualBox стоит Ubuntu 18.04, сеть настроена через NAT. Доступ в интернет осуществляется через прокси. В гостевой машине настройки прокси прописаны в `/etc/environment` и в `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10proxy`. При попытке сделать `apt-get update` 
выдает что не может подключится proxy:

> Could not connect to 10.128.128.125:3128 (10.128.128.125), connection timed out

при этом `10.128.128.125` пингуется.

Вот вывод `ifconfig -a`

> ```
> enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
>     inet 10.0.2.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.2.255
>     inet6 fe80::2aa3:8c94:1293:730c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
>     ether 08:00:27:4f:f9:ee  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
>     RX packets 172  bytes 37793 (37.7 KB)
>     RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>     TX packets 335  bytes 41101 (41.1 KB)
>     TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
> ```

Вывод `ip route` на гостевой OS

> ```
> default via 10.0.2.2 dev enp0s3 proto dhcp metric 20100 
> 10.0.2.0/24 dev enp0s3 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.2.15 metric 100 
> 169.254.0.0/16 dev enp0s3 scope link metric 1000
> ```

`ping 10.0.2.15` из хостовой OS выдает

> ```
> Обмен пакетами с 10.0.2.15 по с 32 байтами данных:
> Ответ от 10.14.0.1: Заданный узел недоступен.
> Ответ от 10.14.0.1: Заданный узел недоступен.
>
> Статистика Ping для 10.0.2.15:
>     Пакетов: отправлено = 2, получено = 2, потеряно = 0
>     (0% потерь)
>  Control-C
>  ^C
> ```

В чем может быть проблема?